# Auth failed: invalid password or missing SSH Key while import project in eclipse docker container

Tags: eclipse, git, docker

My operating system: ubuntu 16.04 eclipse 4.0 docker image

While doing import project -> from Git, I get the error:

> ssh://... Auth Failed: invalid password or missing ssh key

I am sharing the local `.ssh` folder with container using `-v /Users/name/.ssh:/root/.ssh:ro` and can successfully import project on eclipse on host without Docker.

Any idea why this error occurs?

**[Update]**

I can clone from command line after login via shell in Docker container.

I thought issue could be Windows->Preferences->General->Network Connections-> SSH2 [Authentication Methods], tried selecting only public key | password and other combinations all throw same error once saved/restated eclipse. I do see keys etc populated properly in network settings - > ssh2 tabs.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the Eclipse running inside the container do so as `root`.
Because an SSH URL will look for its key in `~/.ssh`, and the container has its /root/.ssh filled with your shared files, not `~<auser>/.ssh`.

Second, check if your SSH key is passphrase-protected (which means you would need, on your host, where SSH is working, an ssh-agent to cache the passphrase)

Comment: i made some updates in the question, seems like some other issue.

Comment: @chappalprasad What is the user you are using SSH after login via shell in Docker container? Is it the same as the one running Eclipse?

Comment: @chappalprasad Can you try and select private keys in Eclipse settings?

Comment: it shows id_dsa and id_rsa, kept id_rsa that i need for cloning url but no luck.

Comment: Can you regenerate those keys without passphrase? For testing? `ssh-keygen -t rsa -P "" -m PEM` (and register the public key to the remote server you are cloning from)

Comment: existing ones are without passphrase only.

Comment: @chappalprasad OK, perfect. Can you add some screenshot of the Eclipse settings, and Eclipse error message? (as well as a link to the Eclipse 4.0 image?)