# Remote Connection with Eclipse: Auth fail

Tags: eclipse, ssh

I'm trying to set up a synchronized PHP project with Eclipse 2023-09. As I understand it, Eclipse uses ssh. I can log into the web-server without password via:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 user@example.com
ssh user@example.com
```

I originally used the wizard, and I found that in `Preferences->Remote Development->Remote Connections` I can edit the settings. I double checked user and host name by pasting them to the command line, selected `Public key based authentication` and added `id_ed25519` to the `Private keys` in the `Preferences->General->Network Connection->SSH2` tab. Since `Add Private Key` browses the `.ssh` directory, this should also be correct.

However, when I try to open it fails due to "Auth fail". No more text! Is there any way to get some more information concerning what actually happens?

The issue seems similar to [Auth failed: invalid password or missing SSH Key while import project in eclipse docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180898/auth-failed-invalid-password-or-missing-ssh-key-while-import-project-in-eclipse), which neither has a solution posted.

The error console shows: `An error occurred loading the SSH2 private keys`

I found this post https://cmljnelson.blog/2020/12/11/problem-using-ssh-keys-and-eclipses-remote-system-explorer/, which stipulates that eclipse cannot handle ed25519 keys. So, I retried with RSA 4096, with the same result. I then reduced even to 1024 bit, with the same result.  The error stack trace says:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@60eebf90
```

Of course, the new keys work fine with `ssh`.

Having found [Create a SSH private key with ssh-keygen that is accepted by JSch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53558436/create-a-ssh-private-key-with-ssh-keygen-that-is-accepted-by-jsch) I regenerated a key using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f ~/.ssh/id_eclipse`. Again I can use this key to connect via `ssh`. Now, I can also load the key into `eclipse` in `General->Network Connection->SSH2->Key Management->Load Existing Key...`. It loads fine and the public key value is the same as the one produced. In the `General` tab I removed all other keys than `id_eclipse`. Still, trying to open the connection I see `Auth fail`, but this time without any new entry in the error log.

Comment: Is there anything related in the _Error Log_ view? If yes, select the error (do not open it, just select it), hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Comment: So, to be more precise, JSch cannot handle ed25519 keys. And the solution would be that [Eclipse TM](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.tm/developer) would switch to something that can handle ed25519 keys as Eclipse JGit already did, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution. But, as described with the new edit, there are appear to be even more issues with this.